# Libreoffice crashes immediately on startup

Tags: libreoffice, apparmor

I am on Ubuntu 19.10, with Libreoffice 6.3.4, and OpenJDK 14 and am unable to launch libreoffice:

libreoffice:

```
Fatal exception: Signal 11
Stack:
/usr/lib/libreoffice/program/libuno_sal.so.3(+0x3d263)[0x7f12ac0fb263]
/usr/lib/libreoffice/program/libuno_sal.so.3(+0x3d3da)[0x7f12ac0fb3da]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(+0x46470)[0x7f12abefa470]
/usr/lib/libreoffice/program/libuno_cppu.so.3(+0x17197)[0x7f12a9e13197]
/usr/lib/libreoffice/program/libuno_cppu.so.3(uno_type_any_assign+0x93)[0x7f12a9e125c3]
/usr/lib/libreoffice/program/libmergedlo.so(+0x28d787d)[0x7f12ae9f487d]
/usr/lib/libreoffice/program/libmergedlo.so(+0x28d7dca)[0x7f12ae9f4dca]
/usr/lib/libreoffice/program/libmergedlo.so(_ZN3utl10ConfigItemC2ERKN3rtl8OUStringE14ConfigItemMode+0x80)[0x7f12ae9eebc0]
/usr/lib/libreoffice/program/libmergedlo.so(+0x2912bf6)[0x7f12aea2fbf6]
/usr/lib/libreoffice/program/libmergedlo.so(_ZN19SvtSysLocaleOptionsC1Ev+0x129)[0x7f12aea31099]
/usr/lib/libreoffice/program/libmergedlo.so(_Z7InitVCLv+0x1b0)[0x7f12aedef2c0]
/usr/lib/libreoffice/program/libmergedlo.so(_Z10ImplSVMainv+0x115)[0x7f12aedf08b5]
/usr/lib/libreoffice/program/libmergedlo.so(soffice_main+0x97)[0x7f12adf1e907]
/usr/lib/libreoffice/program/soffice.bin(+0x10b0)[0x5649106b80b0]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(__libc_start_main+0xf3)[0x7f12abedb1e3]
/usr/lib/libreoffice/program/soffice.bin(+0x10ee)[0x5649106b80ee]
```

I see that apparmor is enforcing and I get these warnings in dmesg output:

```
[Mon Feb 24 10:10:10 2020] kauditd_printk_skb: 4 callbacks suppressed
[Mon Feb 24 10:10:10 2020] audit: type=1400 audit(1582557010.883:1138): apparmor="ALLOWED" operation="open" info="Failed name lookup - disconnected path" error=-13 profile="libreoffice-soffice" name="usr/share/drirc.d" pid=17701 comm="soffice.bin" requested_mask="r" denied_mask="r" fsuid=1000 ouid=0
[Mon Feb 24 10:10:10 2020] audit: type=1400 audit(1582557010.883:1139): apparmor="ALLOWED" operation="open" info="Failed name lookup - disconnected path" error=-13 profile="libreoffice-soffice" name="usr/share/drirc.d" pid=17701 comm="soffice.bin" requested_mask="r" denied_mask="r" fsuid=1000 ouid=0
[Mon Feb 24 10:10:10 2020] audit: type=1400 audit(1582557010.883:1140): apparmor="ALLOWED" operation="open" info="Failed name lookup - disconnected path" error=-13 profile="libreoffice-soffice" name="usr/share/drirc.d" pid=17701 comm="soffice.bin" requested_mask="r" denied_mask="r" fsuid=1000 ouid=0
[Mon Feb 24 10:10:10 2020] audit: type=1400 audit(1582557010.883:1141): apparmor="ALLOWED" operation="open" info="Failed name lookup - disconnected path" error=-13 profile="libreoffice-soffice" name="usr/share/drirc.d" pid=17701 comm="soffice.bin" requested_mask="r" denied_mask="r" fsuid=1000 ouid=0
[Mon Feb 24 10:10:10 2020] audit: type=1400 audit(1582557010.887:1142): apparmor="ALLOWED" operation="open" info="Failed name lookup - disconnected path" error=-13 profile="libreoffice-soffice" name="usr/share/drirc.d" pid=17701 comm="soffice.bin" requested_mask="r" denied_mask="r" fsuid=1000 ouid=0
[Mon Feb 24 10:10:10 2020] audit: type=1400 audit(1582557010.899:1143): apparmor="ALLOWED" operation="open" info="Failed name lookup - disconnected path" error=-13 profile="libreoffice-soffice" name="usr/lib/libreoffice/program/services" pid=17693 comm="soffice.bin" requested_mask="r" denied_mask="r" fsuid=1000 ouid=0
[Mon Feb 24 10:10:10 2020] audit: type=1400 audit(1582557010.899:1144): apparmor="ALLOWED" operation="open" info="Failed name lookup - disconnected path" error=-13 profile="libreoffice-soffice" name="overlay/home/user/.config/libreoffice/4/user/SafeMode" pid=17693 comm="soffice.bin" requested_mask="r" denied_mask="r" fsuid=1000 ouid=1000
```

I have attempted to stop apparmor (systemctl stop apparmor), but I still get those warning messages and libreoffice fails to start.

I am running Ubuntu with overlayfs root.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have temporarily disabled the apparmor profiles via:

1. running `apparmor_parser -R <path to profile>`
   usr.lib.libreoffice.program.soffice.bin
   usr.lib.libreoffice.program.xpdfimport
   usr.lib.libreoffice.program.senddoc
   usr.lib.libreoffice.program.oosplash
2. permanently disabling profile via symlinking `<path to profile> /etc/apparmor.d/disable/<profile-to-disable>`

Comment: I think this is more of a bug or poor implementation. You should not have to disable the security module of the kernel to run an office application...

Answer (score 0):

I found that the usr.lib.libreoffice.program.oosplash has a typo in it.  And, it keeps you from disabling the profile.

What was downloaded and in the file at line 17:

*profile **libreoffice-oopslash** /usr/lib/libreoffice/program/oosplash flags=(complain) {*

Change to:

*profile **libreoffice-oosplash** /usr/lib/libreoffice/program/oosplash flags=(complain) {*

For this to run from this point on you have to fool apparmor into disabling the misspelled profile.

#`sudo cp /etc/apparmor.d/usr.lib.libreoffice.program.oosplash /etc/apparmor.d/usr.lib.libreoffice.program.oopslash`

In this bogus cp change line 17 to reflect:

*profile libreoffice-**oopslash** /usr/lib/libreoffice/program/**oopslash** flags=(complain) {*

Now disable the profile using apparmor

# `sudo aa-disable /etc/apparmor.d/usr.lib.libreoffice.program.oopslash`

Confirm that libreoffice_oopslash is no longer in complain mode.

# `sudo aa-status`

Now delete the offending profile.

# `sudo rm -f /etc/apparmor.d/usr.lib.libreoffice.program.oopslash`

This happened recently around JAN '23 to my libreoffice.  It is now resolved. Once able to actually disable the profile, libreoffice was working once again.

Investigating now why we even have to disable apparmor for it.

I hope this is helpful.

Comment: Continued working on this and found you can leave the profile enabled if you toggle the profile to unconfined.  Look at line 30 of the profile file.  It is set to "/usr/lib/libreoffice/program/soffice.bin rmpx,".  Change it to "/usr/lib/libreoffice/program/soffice.bin rmpux,".  Then you should be able to enable the profile and run libreoffice.