# restored disk image on same HDD with Clonezilla and Ubuntu 18.04.5 LTS boots up more slowly

Tags: boot, dual-boot, clonezilla

this relates to my laptop HP 250 with a dual boot HDD with Win10. I assume the Ubuntu boot up time increased with the updates but since I restored an image on the same HDD it's got much worse. I also expanded the ubuntu partition after restoring the image but this didn't seem to worsen the boot up time.

`systemd-analyze blame` showed `apt-daily.service` was taking 58 seconds and I fixed it by [setting the schedule of apt-daily.service to run randomly between 15 min and 45 min after booting](https://askubuntu.com/questions/800479/ubuntu-16-04-slow-boot-apt-daily-service)

I just timed the boot up time and it's as follows:

- 40 seconds after pushing start the GRUB menu pops up (for just 2 seconds, as I set it)
- 1 minute later the Ubuntu logo with the dots switching red/white shows up
- ~1.5 minutes later the logging screen appears
  -> Total ~3 min & 10 secs

This is the current `systemd-analyze blame`

```
     23.157s dev-sda3.device
     23.140s systemd-journal-flush.service
      9.582s plymouth-quit-wait.service
      7.181s snapd.service
      6.750s NetworkManager-wait-online.service
      6.551s systemd-tmpfiles-setup-dev.service
      3.838s mysql.service
      3.546s networkd-dispatcher.service
      3.021s keyboard-setup.service
      2.867s dev-loop11.device
      2.686s NetworkManager.service
      2.492s dev-loop13.device
      2.485s dev-loop21.device
      2.402s dev-loop17.device
      2.247s udisks2.service
      2.239s dev-loop20.device
      2.066s dev-loop4.device
      1.944s dev-loop7.device
      1.802s dev-loop18.device
      1.797s grub-common.service
```

And `systemd-analyze critical-chain` copi-pasted below with [screenshot here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G7Y3b.png)

graphical.target @1min 47.284s
└─multi-user.target @1min 47.284s
└─teamviewerd.service @1min 44.449s +71ms
└─network-online.target @1min 44.447s
└─NetworkManager-wait-online.service @1min 37.696s +6.750s
└─NetworkManager.service @1min 35.005s +2.686s
└─dbus.service @1min 34.059s
└─basic.target @1min 34.034s
└─sockets.target @1min 34.034s
└─snapd.socket @1min 34.006s +28ms
└─sysinit.target @1min 33.967s
└─systemd-timesyncd.service @28.356s +245ms
└─systemd-tmpfiles-setup.service @28.031s +322ms
└─local-fs.target @28.029s
└─run-user-1000-gvfs.mount @1min 58.829s
└─run-user-1000.mount @1min 54.722s
└─local-fs-pre.target @10.458s
└─systemd-tmpfiles-setup-dev.service @3.906s +6.
└─kmod-static-nodes.service @3.801s +103ms
└─systemd-journald.socket @3.801s
└─system.slice @3.800s
└─-.slice @3.791s

So can the values from the main contributors be reduced somehow? Or what else can I do to shorten the boot up time? I have seen that dmesg can be useful, any guidance on how to check it please?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I would investigate UUIDs. Since you changed a partition. You may have an entry in fstab referring to a missing UUID? Some other issues. https://askubuntu.com/questions/1284302/is-it-possible-to-make-ubuntu-20-04-boot-faster In dmesg, you can search for long times between entries or repeated tries at loading a driver.

Comment: Thanks @oldfred  `/etc/fstab` lacks entries of two partitions, windows one and an NTFS one which I use to just store files. It mounts automatically on bootup so maybe this fact is delaying the process. 

And the main time gaps in `desmeg` are

`[    2.844226] clocksource: Switched to clocksource tsc
[   35.738161] random: crng init done`

and

`[   68.828318] audit: type=1400 audit(1618028962.367:11): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_load" profile="unconfined" name="libreoffice-xpdfimport" pid=854 comm="apparmor_parser"
[  134.622266] Bluetooth: BNEP (Ethernet Emulation) ver 1.3`

Comment: Not familiar with either of those issues. But why is loading a LibreOffice file in boot? Seems a bit unusual.

Comment: I'm also surprised about the libreoffice one, I've seen other questions but no revealing answers.There's something I can try for the clocksource one, let's see

Comment: Found this, do not know if it applies or not. https://askubuntu.com/questions/1212480/libreoffice-crashes-immediately-on-startup I have LibreOffice, and do not have that issue with default Kubuntu install.